# How to open and minimize external app to system tray in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt5, qprocess

`QProcess` can be used to open external program, but it will always open an app to the front of all other windows.

Is there a way to open an external app and then minimize/hide this opened app to the system tray?

```
QString path = QString("external app path here").replace("/", "\\");

QProcess process;
process.start(path); //open the external app, but it will stay on top of other windows 
if (process.isOpen()) {
    //then minimize this app to system tray;
}
```

Is this(`open and minimize external app to system tray`) achievable using Qt methods?

If Qt has no way to minimize opened external app to system tray. Do I have to use Windows API? Any advice or example code would be appreciated.

Comment: Nitpick: you mean either the *taskbar* or the *notification area* (of the taskbar), not the "tray". See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030910-00/?p=42583

Comment: You can provide a *recommendation* to the process with CreateProcess(), STARTUPINFO.wShowWindow member.  That kinda defeats the point of using Qt, you'd be ahead by creating a shortcut to the process (a .lnk file) and start that one instead.  Beware that it is just a recommendation, many programs ignore it.  You'll quickly find out from the way the shortcut behaves.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be specific to Qt. Perhaps [Qt session management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/session.html) could be relevant.

It is a matter of [window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) and of [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment). Both are provided by (very broadly speaking) your "operating system" and are not tied to one particular process using Qt.

The system tray belongs to the desktop environment. A particular process using Qt has no reason to minimize it. The minimization of the system tray is the business of the desktop environment (not of one particular Qt application). I see no reason why your application would do that (remember that your user could also run other applications, which are even more important to him than yours and which also interact with or require using the system tray).

Of course, Qt provides an API to *interact* with the window manager and the desktop environment.

PS. On Linux, the convention between a Qt application and the window manager or desktop environment are documented in EWMH and ICCCM. You need to find the equivalent for Windows. I never used Windows so I don't know them. On Linux, one can code a window manager using Qt.

Comment: As you said, Qt provides some ways to interact with the windows manager and desktop environment. Do you know how I can achieve that using Qt methods? Because I am not familiar with the system API.

Comment: The Qt documentation is extremely well written, IMHO. So please read it *carefullly*. You may need to read about the part of Qt which is Windows specific. I never read it, because I never used Windows.